# How to find leak in washing machine?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, washing-machine

My Bosch WAS32783SN washing machine that is 7 years old, and often I get Error F-23, which according to [this list](http://www.fixya.com/support/t4178470-code_f23_logixx_r_nrepeated_sound) is

> F23 is flood protection in base of machine activated. Pull machine forward onto a towel, pivot if 45 degrees forward onto the front feet (ie lift back feet of the floor about a foot) If water runs out from under the machine this will prove this. You will find that the machine will probably work ok now, but you will have to trace the leak of it will reoccur. likely causes are tear in door seal, leaky inlet valve, blocked dispenser inlet or as simple as something was caught in door on previous cycle allowing water to run down the front of the unit and into the base.

which could be the case, as tilting it does *fix* the problem and a bit of water is coming out.

**Question**

So the big question is, how can I figure out where the leak is coming from?

Comment: Have you ever cleaned the washing machine's filter?  It is not common knowledge they exist but they're suppose to be cleaned monthly... Try that first and see if it is packed with garbage causing a block.

Answer (score 2):

#### There is some water leak inside your appliance.

You can diagnose it carefully. First statically, then you can try to observe the problem when the appliance is running.

1. Ensure being safe - [check your loose clothes, long hair, gloves or jewellery](https://www.worksafebc.com/en/resources/health-safety/hazard-alerts/the-hazards-of-loose-clothing-gloves-long-hair-and-jewellery), the following operation is at your own risk.
2. Remove the covers of the washing machine, so you can see inside, but keep everything plugged in.

   - rear cover
   - top cover (optional)
      
     This is only for observation. Do not touch anything inside.
3. Pour some water into open door, then inspect the bottom of the appliance case for accumulating water (use torch to see better). If the water starts appearing, skip to the last step below.
4. Start the washing cycle (can be without load, without detergent).
5. Using bright torch, inspect the bottom of the appliance case for accumulating water and try to identify location where the water comes in. (Do not get close, do not touch, stay in safe distance, just observe.)
6. If you got an idea, end the cycle, drain the water, unplug the machine completely and continue with regular repair/replacement of the defective part. If you did not get an idea, then this is probably beyond your DIY capabilities and call repair service.